# How to prove that $\int_0^1 e^{x^2-x} dx$ is more than than $e^{(\frac{-1}{4})}$, and less than 1 using series expansions alone?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

My first  instinct was to attempt to use its Taylor expansion
which is
$$ 1- x+\frac{3x^2}{2}-\frac{7x^3}{6}...$$
which allows me prove prove it's less than 1  by computing
$\int_0^1 (1- x+\frac{3x^2}{2}-\frac{7x^3}{6})dx $

however, I have no idea how to numerically verify if it's more than $e^{\frac{-1}{4}}$.

Could someone please give any advice, or guide me to a theorem which allows me to achieve the same (using expansions alone).

Note:- I'm aware that there are other methods of solving this, however, I'm interested in proving this by using expansions.

Comment: I'm prone to using the convexity of $e^x$ and the fact that $e > 2.2$ but that's not what you wanted. Have you tried Taylor expanding at a point other than $x = 0$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what would an appropriate point be ? the expansion at $e^{-0.25}$

Comment: Is it not sufficient to use $0\le x(1-x)\le\frac14$ on $x\in[0,1]$? No series expansion required, just monotonicity.

Comment: A simpler way to use series expansion is to show $e^t$ is increasing for $t>0$ as all terms are increasing.  Then it is enough to show $0< x- x^2 < \frac14$ for $x \in (0, 1)$ and take exponents and reciprocals before integrating.  Using exactly your series looks too cumbersome for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to prove it's more than $e^{-0.25}$, @LutzLehmann, not $e^{0.25}$

Comment: @Macavity, that looks interesting, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: as both the answers are excellent, I hope the community is fine if I don't accept any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series expansion approach doesn't actually formally prove the upper bound because including only a finite number of terms does not tell you the amount of error.

Instead, the correct reasoning is to note that $x^2 - x \le 0$ for all $0 \le x \le 1$, since $x^2 - x = x(x-1)$ implies that for any $x \in (0,1)$, $x > 0$ but $x-1 < 0$, so their product is negative; and when $x \in \{0, 1\}$, $x^2 - x = 0$.

Hence $$e^{x^2 - x} \le e^0 = 1$$ on this interval and $$\int_{x=0}^1 e^{x^2 - x} \, dx \le 1.$$  Finally, the inequality is strict because when $x = 1/2$, $x^2 - x = -1/4 < 0$.

For the lower bound, we note $$x^2 - x = (x-1/2)^2 - 1/4,$$ and since the square of a real number is never negative, $$x^2 - x \ge -1/4.$$  Thus using the same reasoning as for the upper bound,

$$\int_{x=0}^1 e^{x^2 - x} \, dx \ge \int_{x=0}^1 e^{-1/4} \, dx = e^{-1/4},$$ and again, the inequality is strict because, for instance, when $x = 0$, $x^2 - x = 0 > -1/4$.

Your original comment, that you are trying to prove the integral is more than $e^{-0.25}$, reflects a misunderstanding of the comment you replied to:  note that the inequality provided is $$0 < \color{red}{x - x^2} < \frac{1}{4},$$ that is to say, $$-\frac{1}{4} < x^2 - x < 0.$$  The original comment's advice is correct as written.

The series approach is destined to fail for the same reason that you cannot assert, for instance,

$$\int_{x=0}^1 1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1^2}{2!} \, dx \le \int_{x=0}^1 e^{-1} \, dx.$$  The next term in the series expansion is $-1/3! < 0$.  In order to use such reasoning you must quantify the error term, and as such, it would be unnecessarily complicated compared to the solution provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I=\int_{0}^{1} e^{(x-1/2)^2} dx$$
$f(x)=e^{(x-1/2)^2}$ in [,1], attains min at $x=1/2$, so $f_{min}=1$ and max at $x=0,1$ so $f_{max}=e^{1/4}$ then we have
$$1 \le e^{(x-1/2)^2} \le e^{1/4} \implies \int _{0}^{1} 1 dx \le I \le \int_{0}^{1} e^{1/4} dx\implies  1\le I \le e^{1/4}.$$
Finally it follows that
$$e^{-1/4}\le \int_{0}^{1} e^{x^2-x} dx \le 1.$$

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but where did you get the $ e^{(x-1/2)^2}$ from?

Comment: Work with $I$ where the actual integral $J=I e^{-1/4}$, since $x^2-x=(x-1/2)^2-1/4$.

Comment: ah, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also you may work starting with $ -1/4  \le  x^2-x \le  0.$

Comment: @fhhh you may now select one answer.

Comment: sorry for selecting the other answer, the amount of detail made it a more appealing choice, I'm sorry.